# Display none/block on div is not working

Tags: css, html, hide, block

i'm trying to get this working but i cant figure out why it wont, is there a way of troubleshooting this i.e to see errors

What i am trying to achieve is to show the info in the showhim div when i hover over  the stat1 div but it aint happening.

I put it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ksvrY/39/

```
<div id="post-wrap">
   <div class="showhim" id="stat1_text">
        This is some example test<br />
        This is another line<br />
        And another one<br />
        And a final one
  </div>


    <div id="stat1" class="stat1">
        <a href="#">Hover over this div</a>
    </div>
</div>

.showhim
{
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.stat1:hover .showhim
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think a style rule called `showhim` that has `display:none` is a little misleading..?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do with css. You'll have to use JavaScript. CSS can only affect child elements or elements sitting beside each other - not parent elements.

Comment: well if you think putting text in a div that is set to display:none is also misleading then i guess your right.

Comment: no, I think hiding an element by applying a class called `showhim` is misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** As pointed out by Paul, you can use the sibling selector.  So there is actually a way to do this with pure css in this case

`.stat1` is not a parent of `.showhim`.

You can use javascript.  So something like (using jQuery):

```
$('.stat1').mouseover(function(){
  $('.showhim').show();
}).mouseout(function(){
  $('.showhim').hide();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ksvrY/50/

Comment: wow that was quick, that sounds logical but how do i fix it, i must put .stat1 in inside the other div? that isn't ideal is there another way to do it and keep them as separate divs

Comment: Perfect, i did already find the solution once people pointed out my errors however your's is much cleaner, for reference this is what i used:

<div id="stat1" class="stat1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('stat1_text').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('stat1_text').style.display = 'none';">

And then:
<div id="stat1_text" style="display: none;">

Thanks so much for everyones help

Answer (score 2):

For it to work, the `.showhim` needs to be a child element of `.stat1`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a sibling select.

```
<div id="post-wrap">
<div id="stat1" class="stat1">
    <a href="#">Hover over this div</a>
</div>

 <div class="showhim" id="stat1_text">
    This is some example test<br />
    This is another line<br />
    And another one<br />
    And a final one
</div>

.showhim
{
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.stat1:hover ~ .showhim
{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with paul

and here's another solution:

move `.showhim` into `#stat1`:

```
<div id="post-wrap">
    <div id="stat1" class="stat1">
        <a href="#">Hover over this div</a>
        <div class="showhim" id="stat1_text">
            This is some example test<br />
            This is another line<br />
            And another one<br />
            And a final one
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```